# I'm getting an DirectoryNotFoundException error after published an blazor assembly application ASP.NET CORE hosted in IIS

Tags: iis, blazor-webassembly, asp.net-blazor, asp.net-core-staticfile

I have in the server-side project a static files' folder to upload images, when I published this project, it gives me this error:

[Error I got in IIS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gPz2b.png)

The folder I'm talking about is here:

[This is where I have the static files folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/35f7A.png)

And this is how I'm telling the application that I have a static files folder in the server-side:

```
       app.UseStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions
        {
            FileProvider = new PhysicalFileProvider(
            Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "upload")),
            RequestPath = "/upload"
        });
```

I hope some of you guys can help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just have to create the `upload` folder by your own in your application folder.